# How do I use .Node files in my Application

Tags: node.js

I want to use [lwip](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip) in my node application. But when I tried `npm install lwip`, it failed on in my environment. So, I followed instructions on the github page, I have the project built for my environment. The output of which is three .Node files: lwip_decoder, lwip_encoder, and lwip_image. how do I use these within my application?

I have this but I keep getting an error that .open is undefined

```
var lwip = require('../../custom_modules/lwip_image');
var img = req.files.image;
var imgPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../public/images', img.name);
lwip.open(imgPath, function (err, image) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(image.width);
        consoel.log(image.height);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(imgPath);
    }
});
```

Comment: did you try `console.log(lwip)`?

Comment: @positlabs : yeah, it produces  { LwipImage: [Function: LwipImage] }

Answer (score 0):

`lwip_image` is not the module you should be requiring.

You still need to `require('lwip')`. You just need to put your build modules into the appropriate place so that `lwip` can use them when it needs to.

Comment: My apologies, I new to using node modules that rely on native code. Can you point me in the right direction on how to determine the appropriate place. After the files are placed, just run npm install again?